# How to change the position title in the fieldset to left of the items

Tags: extjs, fieldset

how to change the position title in the fieldset? help me,
I want the title of fieldset shown on the left

Answer (score 1):

you want fieldset at right side. that means add style like this,

```
      .rightAligned .x-toggle {
      float:right;
      margin-right:1em;
      }
```

Comment: you mean left side to the checkbox or you looking for leftside to items(i mean it will open from left to right)??